# Return doesn't work but print works

Tags: php

I'm trying to search in multidimensional array and get the value but return doesn't work.

```
function search($arr,$q){
  foreach($arr as $key => $val){
    if(trim($key) == $q) return $arr;
    else if(is_array($val))  search($val,$q);
  }
}
```

But echo and print work.

Where is the problem?

Comment: Your recursive call doesn't return. Use `return search($val,$q);`.

Comment: Actually you seem to be mixing up some variables there. Your first `return` should probably be `return $val`, or maybe add some way of identifying which `$key` (including potential recursion) held the target value.

Comment: When I add `return` before `search($val,$q)`, the function doesn't work at all. Even echo or print.

Comment: change to `if(trim($key) == $q) return 1;
    else if(is_array($val))  search($val,$q); else return 2;` and `echo search($yourarray,$yourvalue);` what the result ?

Comment: it always returns 2 @salari mameri

Comment: That means $q not in $array and after that, $val is not array. as the result not return anything

Comment: @bng Can you tell me your requirement exactly ?

Comment: I have a multidimensional array and I want to search in it by key and get its value. @Sudharshan Nair

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you've solved it already, but this is a solution that might help you on your way:

```
<?php
$arr = ['firstname' => 'John', 'lastname' => 'Dough', 'jobs' => ['job1' => 'writer', 'job2' => 'dad']];

$result = null; // the container for the search result
$key = 'job1'; // the key we are looking for
findKey($arr, $key, $result); // invoke the search function

/** print the result of our search - if key not found, outputs 'NULL' */
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($result); // output: string(6) "writer"
echo '<pre>';

/**
 * @param array $arr        the multidimensional array we are searching
 * @param string $key       the key we are looking for
 * @param $result           passed by reference - in case the key is found, this variable 'stores' the corresponding value.
 */
function findKey($arr = [], $key = '', &$result)
{
    foreach ($arr as $key0 => $value0) {
        if($key0 == $key) {
            $result = $value0;
        }
        if(is_array($value0)) {
            findKey($value0, $key, $result);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: thank you but if the key has an array then the function returns the first element of the array. I want to get the array.

Comment: I solved. I changed from `$result = $value0;` to  `$result = $arr;` Thanks again :)

Comment: That's weird, if I test for key 'jobs', the code does return the array: `array(2) {
  ["job1"]=>
  string(6) "writer"
  ["job2"]=>
  string(3) "dad"
}`